# How to use Espresso Test Recorder in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

I have been struggling to get this to work. I am choosing Espresso as a framework to test because I see there is support in Xamarin Test Cloud, Firebase and Amazon Device Farm which makes it easier to port the tests.

Also, I like the fact that you can just record a test with Android Studio. The problem is that my clicks are not being catched. Only the ones that I made on the Back button.

It seems all the Touchable views in RN are being ignored. I understand RN creates Views in a different way, and also there is no resourceId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had the same error, for some reason Espresso does not support full Test Recorder clicks, you can do a few with the recorder but you will need to do some manually as this video says

https://youtu.be/JRkDVvB106k?t=2m4s

as the documentation says

> espresso-core - Contains core and basic View matchers, actions, and
>   assertions. See Basics and Recipes.

https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/index.html

Comment: Do you also experience a weird behavior when putting information in InputTexts? Mine is adding a 2 second delay on each key press, I assume due to RN updating the state.

Comment: yes i noticed that the app automatically added a thread sleep bigger each time, i mean, first time was like 2 seconds and then every Thread.sleep was with more time... its weird yes, is better to do the test recorder and then edit it all manually

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same. Just using it for a dummy file and edit it manually. Alright, I'll give it a few days to see if someone adds some light on this, otherwise I'll just give the answer to you as it clearly the current behavior.

Comment: dont worry and hope my answer helps , happy coding :)